# HTML5 Canvas Drawing functions blocks other JS functions if isn't declared as first

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, path, drawing

So I have this function which I use to draw a triangle to make a "Comic Cloud". Well anyway, here's the code:

```
function drawTriangle(param)
{
var context = document.getElementById("triangle" + param).getContext("2d");

context.shadowColor   = '#111111';
context.shadowBlur    = 1;
context.shadowOffsetX = 3;
context.shadowOffsetY = 3;
context.fillStyle     = '#FFFFFF';
context.lineWidth     = 1;

context.beginPath();
    context.lineTo(16, 0);
    context.lineTo(8, 10);
    context.lineTo(0, 0);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
}
```

I keep this declarated in functions.js included in  section
Then, at the end of HTML file, I include script.js file in which I call this function:

```
for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
drawTriangle(i);
};
```

The problem is, that every code written after call of this function, is not being executed. Of course, it's not a problem that it will be called as last JS function, but feeling that I'm doing something wrong is annoying me.

So any ideas? Tips? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Usually, if something kills all code execution, it's because it's throwing an error.

Comment: Also, the most likely error here is that it can't find the element with id `triangle1`, `triangle2`, or `triangle3`. Are you sure those elements are all in the DOM when this is called?

Comment: thanks a lot mate! that was the reason (missing elements in HTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here but if this `document.getElementById("triangle" + param)` returns `null` (if the ID does not exist) then you've got a problem.

Because there is no `null.getContext("2d");`!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run your code inside a .ready from jquery (http://api.jquery.com/ready/) or another way let your DOM load before your make your getElementById() calls.

I lost hours several times before I add this standard to my implementations.